# Vertically center a flex item whos parent is flex-column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I can't make my flex item be vertically aligned in the remaining space it has.

This is what I currently have:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="parent d-flex flex-column py-2">

  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff"></img>
      <!-- need to vertically center this image -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula
      arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Aenean imperdiet. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa quis
      enim. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. In turpis. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Cras id dui. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy
      id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to vertically center the image within its container, but it doesn't work.
I tried using align-items-center, align-self-center and even justify-content-center maybe because it's a column direction, in multiple places, but non works. The image always shows at the top of the container.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

I didn't notice you mentioned your code in example it's just a part of content and used as right side of page.
Regarding that, I've simulated height of .parent block to stretch it.

The point is, BS5 .container not flex by itself. You have to add **.d-flex class** of **display: flex; property** to handle it in flex-way, see code comments for more details.

```css
/* simulate parent height */
.parent {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

/* show containers' area */
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* code for Option-2 */
/* :first-of-type - will be applied only for first .container */
.parent.parent--tmp > .container:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Option-1: changing markup -->
<div class="parent d-flex flex-column py-2">
  <!-- 
    update container class list 
    add "d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
  -->
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <!-- adjust closing tag for image -->
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" />
      <!-- need to vertically center this image -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p>
        Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula
        arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Aenean imperdiet. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa
        quis enim. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. In turpis. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Cras id dui. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet,
        nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Option-2: update only by CSS rule -->
<!-- added "parent--tmp" just for example purposes -->
<div class="parent parent--tmp d-flex flex-column py-2">
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <!-- adjust closing tag for image -->
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" />
      <!-- need to vertically center this image -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p>
        Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula
        arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Aenean imperdiet. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa
        quis enim. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. In turpis. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Cras id dui. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet,
        nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Outdated answer:

Check [BS grid system and alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/#alignment) how to make it two rows.

Here is code example:

```css
.parent.d-flex {
  flex-direction: row !important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="display-6">Without markup changes</p>
<div class="parent d-flex flex-column py-2">

  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/300/200.jpg?hmac=WSdbBEXvCVSqNN1HnCzm7ohp6DhAJfl9t3TcqBNDn_Q" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p>Vivamus euismod mauris. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
        et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed hendrerit. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Praesent
        vestibulum dapibus nibh. Cras varius. Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in,
        sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas
        libero turpis vel mi. Quisque id mi. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Proin viverra, ligula
        sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<hr />

<p class="display-6">BS 5 example</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/300/200.jpg?hmac=WSdbBEXvCVSqNN1HnCzm7ohp6DhAJfl9t3TcqBNDn_Q" />
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <p>Vivamus euismod mauris. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
        et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed hendrerit. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Praesent
        vestibulum dapibus nibh. Cras varius. Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in,
        sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas
        libero turpis vel mi. Quisque id mi. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Proin viverra, ligula
        sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use that, because my code above is just part of the entire page. It's the right half of the page and if I change that it completely breaks everything

Comment: Got it, I'll try to add styles to use existing markup

Comment: @TheArchitect I've made updates to code snippet, you can take a look

Comment: Thank you. In your snippet, the image appears to the left of the text, instead of above the text

Comment: @TheArchitect I've made one more example with your specifications (updated upper part). Hope this time it will help you.